# Unable to connect to IBM Mobile first 7.1 server from remote machine

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Am trying to build a simple `mobile first 7.1` application deployed on the `windows server` (Liberty profile). Am using the below code in the `main.js` file

```
WL.Client.connect({
         onSuccess: function () {
                console.log("Connected to MFP");
                WL.Client.checkForDirectUpdate();
            },
            onFailure: function (f) {
                console.log("Failed to connect to MFP, not sure what to do now.", f);
            }
         });
```

It is giving me the below error in client side.

Failed to connect to `MFP`, not sure what to do now.

> class {status: 404, errorCode: "UNEXPECTED_ERROR", errorMsg: "The
>   server was unable to process the request from the application. Please
>   try again later.", invocationContext: undefined}

Note : The same setup works fine in mobile first server deployed in `eclipse`.

Steps I tried:

1. checked wlclient.properties which has correct values
2. tried to call the remote machine mfpconsole url from mobile and its works fine.
3. enabled trace logs logging

`traceSpecification="com.ibm.puremeap.*=all:com.ibm.worklight.*=all:com.worklight.*=all"`

but its logging any exception.

Comment: Can you check whether you can able to access your MobileFirst Console from the browser of the phone or simulator in which you are facing this issue?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes am able to access the url of mobile first console in the phone

Comment: Can you share me the wireshark network capture between client and server ?

Comment: @Rama,can you capture network traffic between client and server? That will tell us what is being sent out from the SDK and the possible causes of the error

Comment: vivin ,vittal will update soon, thank for the reply

Comment: I think network connectivity is fine between client and server. I have identified that the mobile first studio plugin version used for developement is different from the mobilefirst server in remote machine. will update soon after solving this versioning issue